# Closing all UDP traffic except DNS resolution

Tags: dns, iptables

This is my iptables settings:

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -s 87.27.77.107/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -j DROP
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -j DROP
-A OUTPUT -p udp -j DROP
```

Trying to allow DNS resolution using the two DNS servers specified in /etc/resolv.conf but I'm having troubles. I tried to open port 53 without restricting source/destination IP address but no luck:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT

# host google.it
;; connection timed out; trying next origin
```

Where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It is not enough to check iptables settings in the beginning; you also have to check them in the end to see the *result* of your commands. **Rules are processed from top to bottom,** and every time you use `-A` (which is short for `--append`), it adds the rule at the bottom – *below* the existing "drop all UDP packets" rule.

Here's what you end up with:

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -s 87.27.77.107/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -j DROP
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -j DROP
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp -j DROP
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

To fix this, move your "accept" rules above the "drop" rule, e.g. by specifying the exact position while inserting or appending (`-I/-A INPUT <lineno>`).

(Even better, prepare a full ruleset in text-file form and load everything at once (iptables-save/restore or even [ferm](http://ferm.foo-projects.org/)) instead of inserting random rules in random places.)

Note that half your accept rules are useless if you're only acting as a DNS client (not a DNS server). Outgoing DNS queries will have 53 as their destination port but *not* as the source port (which is instead randomized); and vice versa, incoming responses will have 53 as source, but a random destination port.